# Silverlight casted object sent by web service error

Tags: c#, silverlight, collections, observable, svc

At server side I have two types of object

```
   [DataContract]
    public class Tablo5 { 
      //common class
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Tablo7 : Tablo5{
     [DataMember]
        public Double {get;set;}
    }
    public class Tablo8 : Tablo5{
     [DataMember]
        public Int32 {get;set;}
    }
```

I add their instances to `List<Tablo5>` and send via web service. On client site I want to cast it back to `Tablo7` and `Tablo8` and use. So we I try to send it, I get `"Server NOT FOUND"` error. Even though when I try to log on server side, until `return` everything is fine. 
Can you hint if something with sending casted objects is wrong or I messed up somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Your serializer need to know Tablo7 inherit from Tablo5 and Tablo8 inherit from Tablo5 :

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Tablo7))]
[KnownType(typeof(Tablo8))]
public class Tablo5 { 
  //common class
}

[DataContract]
public class Tablo7 : Tablo5{
    [DataMember]
    public Double MyProp {get;set;}
}

[DataContract]
public class Tablo8 : Tablo5{
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 MySecondProp {get;set;}
}
```

After refresh your proxy on client side

Comment: Thank you. It was the issue. ^__^